# Zoom in effect on background image

Tags: css

Here's is link to a website http://newworldorder.com/ , whenever I load the page, I see the background zoom in for like 2 seconds, is it possible to achieve this with css? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: If you inspect that site with your browser's dev tools you can see how they use transition and transform/scale on the div with the background image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what you are really asking, but this might be what you are looking for:

```
     html, body {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200") top center no-repeat;
    animation: animateBg forwards 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes animateBg{
    from { background-size: 200px; }
    to { background-size: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this effect, but without hover, just on load

Comment: Just re-posted your solution.

Comment: Just clarity. Stack wants as much info as possible. Be sure to read our guidelines to make sure your comment won't get downvoted like this. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Although, it resets to 1x scale at the end.

```html
<style>
div {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547898812-9e25c5a693e0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1936&q=80");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center-top;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 5s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }

}
</style>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;"></div>
</body>
```